# What are the advantages of normalizing a database?

Tags: java, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I really cant get a good solid understanding of this. I see a lot of examples in the internet but lacking explanation on why. For example, you have two kinds of users in an application, a customer and a manager. What are the advantages of creating a separate "user_type" table instead of incorporating the "user_type" column in a user table. Another example is creating a separate table for a category of a product instead of putting the category field in the product table. I really can't get my head around this. What are the advantages of db normalization? And the disadvantages of duplicate data in a database?

Comment: Creating a user_type table instead of a single column has nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated purpose of normalization is to prevent anomalous data from getting into the database.

Such as, take a very simple user entity:

```
create table Users(
  ID        int auto_generated primary key,
  LastName  varchar( 16 ) not null,
  FirstName varchar( 16 ) not null
);
```

Now it turns out there can be two types of users: Manager (M) or Peon (P). Also, for managers, we need to know how many people directly report to them and for peons, we need to know if they have a forklift license. Let's just throw that into the table:

```
create table Users(
  ID           int auto_generated primary key,
  LastName     varchar( 16 ) not null,
  FirstName    varchar( 16 ) not null,
  UserType     char( 1 ) not null,
  DirectReps   int,
  HasFLLicense boolean
);
```

This should start all kinds of alarms going off in your head. What can go wrong?

- The only valid values for UserType (at this point) are 'M' or 'P'. This field, however, can contain any single character. We can create a "check" on this column, but that will create another problem which I will cover later.
- The DirectReps and HasFLLicense fields are only applicable if the UserType field contains 'M' or 'P' respectively. There is no way to enforce this internally -- it would have to be done with triggers and/or app code.

There are no easy ways to enforce these new constraints. And we all know that no matter how careful we are, sooner or later we will have UserType values other than 'M' or 'P' and/or values in DirectReps or HasFLLicense inappropriately. This is anomalous data.

If you look closely, the fields LastName, FirstName and UserType has a functional dependency only on ID. However, DirectReps and HasFLLicense are also dependent on UserType. This new table is not in 2nf.

Normalizing this table can be done is several different ways so I won't go into that. ([Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151046/63467) is one method I presented earlier today.) Needless to say, the end result should be done so that a DirectReps value cannot exist unless the UserType value is 'M' and a HasFLLicense value cannot exist unless the UserType value is 'P'.

Now let's look at just the normalized table:

```
create table Users(
  ID           int auto_generated primary key,
  LastName     varchar( 16 ) not null,
  FirstName    varchar( 16 ) not null,
  UserType     char( 1 ) check( UserType in( 'M', 'P' )
);
```

There are some normalization methods that would also remove the `UserType` field from the table but let's leave it here for now. The following applies no matter where it is located.

The problem appears when you consider that, sooner or later, a third type will be required. And at different points another and then another and you get the idea. Each time we would have to issue an `alter table` command just to rewrite the check constraint. This is like completely demolishing and rebuilding your home just to replace your living room sofa. All the code that accesses this table (including views) would have to be, at a minimum, recompiled and possibly rewritten. Let's face it, `alter table` is a non-trivial operation.

How much better to have a lookup table containing a record for every user type:

```
create table UserTypes(
  ID      char( 1 ) not null primary key, -- 'M' or 'P' or whatever
  Name    varchar( 16 ) not null,  -- "Manager" or "Peon" or whatever
  ...     -- other possible attributes
);
```

Then the `UserType` field may be defined:

```
  UserType     char( 1 ) not null references UserTypes( ID )
```

Now adding a type 'A' or 'F' or whatever is simply a matter of inserting a record into the UserTypes table. Existing code is unaffected. Of course, the app code will ultimately have to be changed to handle the new types, but the app developers can do this now at their leisure.

Don't just design for current requirements. Also design for reasonably expected future requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantages of duplicate data is that you have to remember where all the copies of the data are and to update all of them when information is changed. Normalization is more about de-duplication than creating separate tables.

In your example of user_type, you can just put that in a column on the user table. The additional table comes in handy if the user can have multiple user types.